# Capture Button Click event of a specific form?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, forms

I have two forms

```
<form name='myform1'>
  <input type='button' class='submitBtn'>
</form>

<form name='myform2'>
  <input type='button' class='submitBtn'>
</form>
```

Both forms have a button with same class. How can I capture click event of only **myform1**'s button(submitBtn) in jQuery?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**WRONG**: u cant have same `id` on a same page

otherwise do below

**TRY this**

```
    $('input[type="button"]').click(function() {
       var formName=$(this).parent('form').attr('name');
       if(formName =='myform1'){ 
          alert( formName+' button is clicked'); 
      } if(formName =='myform2'){ 
         alert( formName+' button is clicked'); 
      }
   });
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/j6c7P/4/)

Comment: this button is not submit button.

Answer (score 2):

It's not allowed to have more than one id with the same value.

Solution: use class names for visual styling and distinct IDs for capturing events.

Answer (score 1):

`id` means **identifier** -- so, it should be unique in the HTML page, to allow one to identify an element.

Still, if you want to get the button which is in the form named `myform1`, you could use something like this :

```
$('form[name="myform1"] input[type="button"]')
```

Comment: Sorry for confusion. Question edited. It is not necessary that both forms will be placed on same page. I am using same js file for all pages.